# Path not allowed on the configured scope in tauri app

Tags: svelte, tauri

I'm using  writeTextFile() function to write json data into this file 'src-tauri/databases/db.json .

The readTextFile(resourcePath) work fine get the data from same json file

i'm using svelte

here the tauri config file look like :

```json
"tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": true,
      "path": {
        "all": true
      },
      "fs": {
        "all": true, 
        "readFile": true,
        "writeFile": true,
        "readDir": true,
        "copyFile": true,
        "createDir": true,
        "removeDir": true,
        "removeFile": true,
        "renameFile": true,
        "exists": true,
        "scope": [
          "$RESOURCE/*",
          "$RESOURCE/databases/*",
          "$RESOURCE/databases/db.json"
        ]
      }
    
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",
      "targets": "all",
      "resources": [
        "databases/*",
        "databases/db.json"
      ]
    }
}
```

here my code :

```js
    import { resourceDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
    import { readTextFile, writeTextFile } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs'

    await writeTextFile({ path: 'databases/db.json' , contents: data })
```

version:

```json
    {
      "name": "svelt-pos",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "tauri": "tauri"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.0",
        "svelte": "^3.54.0",
        "vite": "^4.2.1",
        "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.2.3"
      }
    }
```